# Calculating a piece of a total in relation to the total in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I get cells C4 and C5 to auto calculate in Excel 2013 so the fee is included in the Total and the total adjust for the fee? I have seen it done but don't know how it was done.

Excel Table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may put in `C4` a `=SUM(C1:C3)*.5%` formula.
Then `=SUM(C1:C4)` in `C5`